# Mongo query to filter out the elements inside an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

There is db structure were the value is array of objects like

```
{
 key : [
  {
   retrive : false
  },
  {
   retrive : true
  }
 ]
}
```

And i want to query only the objects were 'retrieve' key is set to true.

Comment: All right i found about the $elemMatch operator which does what i want, but it is said that it only retrieves the first document matches but what i want is like multiple $elemMatch

Answer (score 0):

```
  db.collection.find({'key.$.retrive':true},function(err,res){


   });
```

Comment: This nothing is retrieved, the query is like
db.collection.find({somekey : someVal, 'key.$.retrive' : true}).pretty();

Comment: replace collection with your collection name.

Comment: There is no reason why you need the ``.$.`` in that query, just ``'key.retrive`` should do.

Comment: @Derick  while accessing field in array we need to specify the '$'.